# How can I return the number of users registered after a specified date?

Tags: users

Ok little stuck on this. I am trying to return the number of users registered after a specific date. So far I have tried the below using after but it is still returning all users regardless of the date.

```
craft.users.status('active,pending').after('2015-06-22').total()
```

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should do it:

```
craft.users.status('active,pending').dateCreated('> 2015-06-22').total()
```

Comment: Perfect cheers @BradBell